# awk/sed extract string from between patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I know there has probably been a few hundred forms of this question asked on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find a suitable answer to my question.

I'm trying to parse through the `/etc/ldap.conf` file on a Linux box so that I can specifically pick out the description fields from between `(description=` and `)`:

```
*-bash-3.2$ grep '^nss_base_passwd' /etc/ldap.conf
```

`nss_base_passwd         ou=People,dc=ca,dc=somecompany,dc=com?one?|(description=TD_FI)(description=TD_F6)(description=TD_F6)(description=TRI_142)(description=14_142)(description=REX5)(description=REX5)(description=1950)*`

I'm looking to extract these into their own list with no duplicates:

```
TD_FI
TD_F6
TRI_142
14_142
REX5
1950
```

(or all on one line with a proper delimiter)

I had played with `sed` for a few hours but couldn't get it to work - I'm not entirely sure how to use the global option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use grep with `-P` option,

```
$ grep '^nss_base_passwd' /etc/ldap.conf | grep -oP '(?<=description\=)[^)]*' | uniq
TD_FI
TD_F6
TRI_142
14_142
REX5
1950
```

**Explanation:**

A positive lookbehind is used in grep to print all the characters which was just after to the `description=` upto the next `)` bracket. `uniq` command is used to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Need to make sure this is limited to lines beginning with "nss_base_passwd"

Comment: These all do exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you to all - you're a lifesaver.

Comment: @AvinashRaj please see my answer, it might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep '^nss_base_passwd' /etc/ldap.conf |
grep -oE '[(]description=[^)]*' | sort -u |
cut -f2- -d=
```

Explanations:

1. With `bash`, if you end a line with `|` (or `||` or `&&`), the shell knows that the command continues on the next line, so you don't need to use `\`.
2. The second `grep` uses the `-o` flag to indicate that the matching expressions should be printed out, one per line. It also uses the `-E` flag to indicate that the pattern is an "Extended" (i.e. normal) regular expression.
3. Since `-o` will print the entire match, we need to extract the part after the prefix, for which we use `cut`, specifying a delimiter of `=`. `-f2-` means "all the fields starting with the second field", which we need in case there is an `=` in the description.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE 'say join(",", /description=\K([^)]+)/g) if /^nss_base_passwd/' /etc/ldap.conf
```

```
TD_FI,TD_F6,TD_F6,TRI_142,14_142,REX5,REX5,1950
```

Answer (score 0):

[Avinash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24313529/2698019) was very close. Here is my improved version:

```
grep '^nss_base_passwd' /etc/ldap.conf | grep -Po '\(description=\K[^)]+' | sort -u
```

There is no need to use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax when you can simply use `\K` (which is actually a shortcut for a corresponding zero-width assertion).

Also, you said that you want NO duplicates, but `uniq` will only remove duplicate adjacent lines, it will not remove duplicates if there is something in between. That's why I am using `sort -u` instead.